# How to iterate between rows of a session with nested arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I don't know how to iterate in between rows of this session and get what I want. I tried many different approaches but didn't get the right result.

```
foreach($this->session->data['cart'] as $key=>$row){
    $this->cart->add($row['product_id'], $row['quantity'], $row['option'], $row['recurring_id'], $row['store_id']);
}
```

OR this for test:

```
foreach($this->session->data['cart']['row'] as $key=>$row){
    print_r($row['product_id']);
    print_r('<hr>');                
}


Array
(
        [num_rows] => 10
        [row] => Array
                (
                        [cart_id] => 126
                        [product_id] => 45
                        [recurring_id] => 0
                        [option] => {"90":["263"],"89":["260"]}
                        [quantity] => 2
                        [store_id] => 2
                )

        [rows] => Array
                (
                        [0] => Array
                                (
                                        [cart_id] => 126
                                        [product_id] => 45
                                        [recurring_id] => 0
                                        [option] => {"90":["263"],"89":["260"]}
                                        [quantity] => 2
                                        [date_added] => 2017-11-08 21:19:56
                                        [store_id] => 2
                                )

                        [1] => Array
                                (
                                        [cart_id] => 127
                                        [product_id] => 46
                                        [recurring_id] => 0
                                        [option] => {"90":["263"],"89":["261"]}
                                        [quantity] => 1
                                        [date_added] => 2017-11-08 21:19:56
                                        [store_id] => 2
                                )...
```

Many thanks for any kind help.

Comment: @coderodour: the same. didn't work.

Comment: try `$this->session->data['cart']['rows']` instead of `$this->session->data['cart']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `$this->session->data['cart']` contains the array you provided after `foreach` loop then you can simply do this:

```
foreach($this->session->data['cart']['rows'] as $key => $row){
    $this->cart->add($row['product_id'], $row['quantity'], $row['option'],  $row['recurring_id'], $row['store_id']);
}
```